# terminal not executing/saving commands

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, high-sierra

My terminal wont "restore all commands"; it only opens up blank window group. This exact thing works on another mac, with the same os version. What am I doing wrong/how can I manually edit the group to do what I need?

[image: terminal "save window group" window]

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this by setting up a profile for each terminal window in Terminal>Preferenes>Profiles (write in the command you want to execute at startup in "Profiles" tab "Run command"), then open each window by right-clicking terminal "New window with a profile" and then saved the window group as I described before, hope this helps somebody

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I was running the commands by typing them at the prompt instead of running the commands using the menubar's **Shell > New Command...**

After doing this Save Windows as Group... worked as expected. A different [more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7053873/518222) helped me get to this solution.